# c++ char memory leakage with valgrind analysis

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have around 350 lines code where I am parsing xml file and creating another 2 sheets out of it using C++.

After adding the last 2 or 3 functions I started having memory error,

> Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)

Removing them didn't solve the error so definitely I edited something else. I searched online and found about valgrind which showed me errors that I can't translate.

As per the valgrind manual, I have to check from below to up so as per the last one,

> ==7276== 4,064 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 52 of 54
>   ==7276==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>   ==7276==    by 0x456BDD: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-5)
>   ==7276==    by 0x4EC260D: _obstack_begin (obstack.c:176)
>   ==7276==    by 0x456FCE: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-5)
>   ==7276==    by 0x43BA49: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-5)
>   ==7276==    by 0x43BAC0: ??? (in /usr/bin/g++-5)
>   ==7276==    by 0x4E5A82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)

For line 291 is the append line in the below code,

```
if (vlan_ether)
sprintf(cConfStr, "**.Switch%ld.eth[%d].queue.VlanClassifier = true\n", srcindex + 1, portno);
else if (!vlan_ether)
sprintf(cConfStr, "**.Switch%ld.eth[%d].queue.etherType = false\n", srcindex + 1, portno);
else
cout << "Switch" << srcindex + 1 << "port# " << portno << " Classifier is not specified." << endl;
confStr.append(string(cConfStr));
```

Removing the above lines didn't do any change, while line 176 is a comment so am hesitating that valgrind is not showing the lines of error.

So I am not sure what to show you in my question from the code. Still I am definite that it should be related to string and char usage In which I used them several times.

```
char cNedStr[600];
char cConfStr[600];

sprintf(cConfStr, "%d ", intervalvector[q]);
confStr.append(string(cConfStr));
```

The Valgrind result as per below,

```
amr@amr-PC:~$ valgrind --leak-check=yes  g++ main.cpp pugixml.cpp headers.h -Wall -std=c++11
```

**EDIT:**

```
amr@amr-PC:~/ClionProjects/converter$ valgrind ./a.out
==7624== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7624== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7624== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7624== Command: ./a.out
==7624== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7624==    at 0x4C2F24B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7624==    by 0x5714FF7: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==7624==    by 0x5715044: exit (exit.c:104)
==7624==    by 0x56FB836: (below main) (libc-start.c:325)
==7624==  Address 0x35663a37323a6536 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7624== 
==7624== 
==7624== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7624==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==7624==   total heap usage: 525 allocs, 525 frees, 214,887 bytes allocated
==7624== 
==7624== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7624==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7624==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7624==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7624==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==7624==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7624== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==7624== 
==7624== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7624== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You are using Valgrind *wrong*. You are checking the *compiler* and not your program. After building your program, you should use e.g. `valgrind ./a.out`. I also recommend you add the `-g` flag when building as it will add debug information and Valgrind will then be able to tell you the file- and function-names where the problems are as well as the exact line numbers.

Comment: Furthermore, if your program crashes you should start by using a *debugger* to catch the crash in action. Then you will be able to locate where it happens as well as examine the values of all involved variables. You of course need to build with debug information (the `-g` flag) for it to work well.

Comment: Lastly, why are you building the *header file*? The file `header.h` should be included in your source (I presume) and should not be compiled.

Comment: +Some programmer dude 

I already tried and removing the line I am suspecting didn't show me any thing. Actually the program runs but not completely. So it is like trial and error adding the breakpoints with no progress.

Because I added all the includes inside the header file, including the pugixml parser header file. Without it the program is not built.

Comment: Regarding the header file, you *do* `#include "header.h"` in your `main.cpp` file? Then that should be all you need. If not then you should probably ask another question about it. As for running in a debugger, if your program is crashing (which is what segmentation fault is) then just `run` the program and the debugger will catch the crash as it happens. No need for breakpoints.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, it is my mistake it worked with out including the header file in the terminal. 

Running with a debugger didn't show which line is causing the memory leak. It just used to give similar Segmentation fault using CLion IDE. I solved it by testing line by line until I found the mistake and corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compile, without the header file, (default output is `a.out`):

```
g++ main.cpp pugixml.cpp -Wall -std=c++11
```

Then check using valgrind:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out
```

**Other comments:**

You could consider adding the following flags to g++:

- -Wextra (more warnings)
- -pedantic (turns off extensions and generates more warnings)
- -g (debug symbols)
- -O3 (maximum optimization, not recommended for debugging!)

Comment: Adding the `-g` flag when building might be a good idea. As well as not building the header file.

Comment: I'd personally avoid -O3 when debugging - as it makes stepping through more insteresting (clearly not related to using valgrind, but it's debugging issues none the less); but that's personal preference